# How do I upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: upgrade

How do I upgrade Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 if there is no upgrade button on my update manager panel?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening to you because your dist-upgrade is set "only for LTS". In order to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 (which is NOT and LTS release) you have to set the upgrade to **For any new version**. You can do this by doing the follow:

Run the update-manager application from the Dash.

In Update Manager, click the **Settings...** button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.

Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.

Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "**For any new version**", and change it if otherwise.
[image: For any new version]
Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.
In Update Manager, click the Check button to check for new updates.

If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.

A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.
Click Upgrade.

Follow the on-screen instructions.